# How to avoid duplicate entries when making a post request?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble when posting an object with a nested object in ASP.NET. I have a Status class that has a User object (the User that posted the Status). When posting the Status in JSON form, it has the user object as well. The problem is, instead of adding the Status with that User, it adds the Status AND a new User, which is obviously not what I want.

Here is what the JSON looks like. The User with the id 2 already exists in the database, but when this is posted, another user is created.

```
{
    "User": {
        "Id": 2,
        "First": "Tobin",
        "Last": "Brown",
        "Email": null,
        "Profile": null,
        "Height": 75,
        "Weight": 165,
        "BirthDate": "1991-04-24T00:00:00"
    },
    "Id": 2,
    "Type": 0,
    "Time": "2015-03-08T11:01:48"
}
```

User class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TeamUser> Teams { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Status class:

```
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StatusType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

Finally here is my controller method that handles the addition of the status to the database using the entity framework:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Status))]
public IHttpActionResult PostStatus(Status status)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Statuses.Add(Status);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(status);
}
```

Why would it be creating a new User if I am passing it the User Id in the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since status entry is new, entity framework treats all its associated objects as new. Your example above could be modified as below

1) Add UserId property to Status class
2) Set UserId property with the corresponding user object's ID in JSON. It will now look like this

```
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Type": 0,
    "UserId": 2,
    "Time": "2015-03-08T11:01:48"
}
```

3) In your controller, set `status.User = null`

The Status table in your database should have the UserId foreign key mapped to ID column of User.

Comment: Thank You! I ended up going with this. It turns out, since I didn't define the foreign key, the entity framework was auto-generating one called `user_Id`. Once I defined it as `UserId` this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `EntityState` to `Unchanged` before you call `db.SaveChanges()`.

Something like below:

```
db.Entry<User>(status.User).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

for more detail visit this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-attach the existing user to the db context (if setting status.User=null doesn't work)

```
if (status.User!=null)
{
    db.Users.Attach(status.User)
    db.Entry<User>(status.User).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```